# Check if mouse is within triangle C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, math, trigonometry

I'm making a application for school in which I have to click a particular object.

EDIT: This is being made in 2D

I have a rectangle, I rotate this rectangle by X.
The rotation of the rectangle has made my rectangles (x,y,width,height) become a new rectangle around the rotated rectangle.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MejMA.png
(excuse me for my terrible paint skills)

The Black lines describe the rotated rectangle, the red lines are my new rectangle.
I need to find out if my mouse is within the black rectangle or not. Whatever rotation I do I already have a function for getting the (X,Y) for each corner of the black rectangle.

Now I'm trying to implement this [Check if point is within triangle (The same side technique)](http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/default.html).

So I can either check if my mouse is within each triangle or if theres a way to check if my mouse is in the rotated rectangle that would be even better.

I practically understand everything written in the triangle document, but I simply don't have the math skills to calculate the cross product and the dot product of the 2 cross products.

This is supposed to be the cross product:

> a × b = |a| |b| sin(θ) n
>
> |a| is the magnitude (length) of vector a
>
> |b| is the magnitude (length) of vector b
>
> θ is the angle between a and b
>
> n is the unit vector at right angles to both a and b

But how do I calculate the unit vector to both a and b?
And how do I get the magnitude of a vector?

EDIT:
I forgot to ask for the calculation of the dotproduct between 2 cross products.

```
function SameSide(p1,p2, a,b)
    cp1 = CrossProduct(b-a, p1-a)
    cp2 = CrossProduct(b-a, p2-a)
    if DotProduct(cp1, cp2) >= 0 then return true
    else return false
```

---

Thank you everyone for your help I think I got the hang of it now, I wish I could accept multiple answers.

Comment: A tutorial on vectors is always welcome: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/Vectors_Basics.aspx

Comment: I will post examplar code on the unit vector in a short while, seem to have missed that on first reading.

Comment: Since you are testing for the presence inside a rectangle, maybe the _test for inside polygon_ is more to your liking. Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon

Comment: Instead of checking triangles I guess it would be easier just to transform your mouuse coordinates into the space of the rotated rectangle and check if the transformed mouse coordinates are within [xmin, ymin] and [xmax, ymax] of the rectangle.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help I think I got the hang of it now, I wish I could accept multiple answers.

Comment: @user3488393 you can allways upvote answers ;)

Comment: there's a superb implementation and an article to it, [pnpoly](http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/~wrf/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html)

Comment: I can't upvote answers until 15 points :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having to carry out loads of check, I would shy away from using square root functions: they are computationally expensive. for comparison purposes, just multiply everything by itself and you can bypass the square rooting:

magnitude of vector = length of vector

If vector is defined as float[3] length can be calculated as follows:

```
double magnitude = sqrt( a[0]*a[0] + a[1]*a[1] + a[2]*a[2] );
```

However that is expensive computationally so I would use

```
double magnitudeSquared = a[0]*a[0] + a[1]*a[1] + a[2]*a[2];
```

Then modify any comparative calculations to use the squared version of the distance or magnitude and it will be more performant.

For the cross product, please forgive me if this maths is shaky, it has been a couple of years since I wrote functions for this (code re-use is great but terrible for remembering things):

```
double c[3];

c[0] = ( a[1]*b[2] - a[2]*b[1] );
c[1] = ( a[2]*b[0] - a[0]*b[2] );
c[2] = ( a[0]*b[1] - a[1]*b[0] );
```

To simplify it all I would put a vec3d in a class of its own, with a very simple representation being:

```
class vec3d
{
    public:
        float x, y, z;
        vec3d crossProduct(vec3d secondVector)
        {
            vec3d retval;
            retval.x = (this.y * secondVector.z)-(secondVector.y * this.z);
            retval.y = -(this.x * secondVector.z)+(secondVector.x * this.z);
            retval.z = (this.x * secondVector.y)-(this.y * secondVector.x);
            return retval;
        }
        // to get the unit vector divide by a vectors length...
        void normalise() // this will make the vector into a 1 unit long variant of itself, or a unit vector
        {
           if(fabs(x) > 0.0001){
              x= x / this.magnitude();
           }
           if(fabs(y) > 0.0001){
              y= y / this.magnitude();
           }
           if(fabs(z) > 0.0001){
              z = / this.magnitude();
           }
        }

        double magnitude() 
        {
            return sqrt((x*x) + (y*y) + (z*z));
        }
        double magnitudeSquared() 
        {
            return ((x*x) + (y*y) + (z*z));
        }
};
```

A fuller implementation of a vec3d class can be had from one of my old 2nd year coding excercises: [.h file](https://code.google.com/p/opengl-computing-project/source/browse/StarHunterV2.0/Lab4/Vec3.h) and [.cpp file](https://code.google.com/p/opengl-computing-project/source/browse/StarHunterV2.0/Lab4/Vec3.cpp).

And here is a minimalist 2d implementation (doing this off the top of my head so forgive the terse code please, and let me know if there are errors):

### vec2d.h

```
#ifndef VEC2D_H
#define VEC2D_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Vec2D {
 private:
  double x, y;
 public:

  Vec2D();                   // default, takes no args
  Vec2D(double, double);     // user can specify init values

  void setX(double);
  void setY(double);

  double getX() const;
  double getY() const;

  double getMagnitude() const;
  double getMagnitudeSquared() const;
  double getMagnitude2() const;
  Vec2D normalize() const;
  double crossProduct(Vec2D secondVector);
  Vec2D crossProduct(Vec2D secondVector);

  friend Vec2D operator+(const Vec2D&, const Vec2D&);
  friend ostream &operator<<(ostream&, const Vec2D&);
};

double dotProduct(const Vec2D, const Vec2D);

#endif
```

### vec2d.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

#include "Vec2D.h"  

// Constructors
Vec2D::Vec2D() { x = y = 0.0; }
Vec2D::Vec2D(double a, double b) { x = a; y = b; }

// Mutators
void Vec2D::setX(double a) { x = a; }
void Vec2D::setY(double a) { y = a; }

// Accessors
double Vec2D::getX() const { return x; }
double Vec2D::getY() const { return y; }
double Vec2D::getMagnitude() const { return sqrt((x*x) + (y*y)); }
double Vec2D::getMagnitudeSquared() const { return ((x*x) + (y*y)); }
double Vec2D::getMagnitude2 const { return getMagnitudeSquared(); }
double Vec2d::crossProduct(Vec2D secondVector) { return ((this.x * secondVector.getY())-(this.y * secondVector.getX()));}
Vec2D crossProduct(Vec2D secondVector) {return new Vec2D(this.y,-(this.x));}

Vec2D Vec2D::normalize() const {   return Vec2D(x/getMagnitude(), y/getMagnitude());}

Vec2D operator+(const Vec2D& a, const Vec2D& b) {  return Vec2D(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y);}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const Vec2D& a) {  output << "(" << a.x << ", " << a.y << ")" << endl;  return output;}

double dotProduct(const Vec2D a, const Vec2D b) {  return a.getX() * b.getX() + a.getY() * b.getY();}
```

### Check if a point is inside a triangle described by three vectors:

```
float calculateSign(Vec2D v1, Vec2D v2, Vec2D v3)
{
  return (v1.getX() - v3.getX()) * (v2.getY() - v3.getY()) - (v2.getX() - v3.getX()) * (v1.getY() - v3.getY());
}

bool isPointInsideTriangle(Vec2D point2d, Vec2D v1, Vec2D v2, Vec2D v3)
{
  bool b1, b2, b3;
  // the < 0.0f is arbitrary, could have just as easily been > (would have flipped the results but would compare the same)
  b1 = calculateSign(point2d, v1, v2) < 0.0f;
  b2 = calculateSign(point2d, v2, v3) < 0.0f;
  b3 = calculateSign(point2d, v3, v1) < 0.0f;

  return ((b1 == b2) && (b2 == b3));
}
```

In the code above if `calculateSign` is in the triangle you will get a `true` returned :)

Hope this helps, let me know if you need more info or a fuller vec3d or 2d class and I can post:)

### Addendum

I have added in a small 2d-vector class, to show the differences in the 2d and 3d ones.

Answer (score 0):

The magnitude of a vector is its *length*. In C++, if you have a vector represented as a `double[3]`, you would calculate the length via

```
#include <math.h>

double a_length = sqrt( a[0]*a[0] + a[1]*a[1] + a[2]*a[2] );
```

However, I understand what you actually want is the cross product? In that case, you may want to calculate it directly. The result is a vector, i.e. c = a x b.
You code it like this for example:

```
double c[3];

c[0] = ( a[2]*b[3] - a[3]*b[2] );
c[1] = ( a[3]*b[1] - a[1]*b[3] );
c[2] = ( a[1]*b[2] - a[2]*b[1] );
```

Comment: This helped quite a bit, I forgot to ask for the calculation of the dotproduct could you maybe help me out?

Comment: The dot product is calculated almost like the length, but without the square root; i.e.: `double dotProduct = a[0]*b[0] + a[1]*b[1] + a[2]*b[2]`.

Comment: One more question, your code looks like the cross product for a 3d vector however I am making it in 2d, does this change things?

Comment: Well, there is no real cross product in 2D. But looking at the site you've linked, I guess you should calculate cross and dot product with 3D vectors. Just use an arbitary (but constant) value for the third component of the start vectors, e.g. `1`.

Comment: @user3488393 The cross product is only defined in 3D. The result of the cross product of two vectors is a new vector perpendicular to both old ones, which means that the new vector would stick out of your drawing plane and this is not 2D anymore ;) You can however add a third dimension and set all your z-Components to zero. Than you can calculate the cross product. But be aware that the result of the cross product will have a non-zero z-component.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the magnitude of vector by `sqrt(x*x + y*y)`. Also you can calculate the crossproduct simpler: `a x b = a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x`. Checking that a point is inside triangle can be done by counting the areas for all 4 triangles. For example a is the area of the source triangle, b,c,d are areas of other ones. If b + c + d = a then the point is inside. Counting the area of triangle is simple: we have vectors a, b that are vertexes of triangle. The area of triangle then is `(a x b) / 2`

Comment: for the area remeber to do (length of a * length of b)/2 or you will get odd results

Answer (score 0):

One simple way without getting into vectors is to check for area.
For example ,lets say you have a rectangle with corners A,B,C,D. and point P.

first calculate the area of rectangle, simply find height and width of the rectangle and multiply.

```
B   D
|  /
| /
|/____ C
A
```

For calculating the height,width take one point lets say A, find its distance from all other three points i.e AB,AC,AD 1st and 2nd minimum will be width,and height, max will be diagonal length.
Now store the points from which you get the height, width, lets says those points are B,C.

So now you know how rectangle looks, i.e

```
B _____ D
 |     |
 |_____|
A       C
```

Then calculate the sum of area of triangles ACP,ABP,BDP,CDP (use heros formula to compute area of rectangle), if it equals to the area of rectangle, point P is inside else outside the rectangle.